# Эмулятор браузера

Tags: node.js

Есть ли методы запуска эмулятора браузера в браузере?
Имеется ввиду не для доступа к логам или в целях манипуляции с DOM, а выводить браузер на web страницу?
желательно на node, но рассмотрю и любые другие технологии.

Comment: Эммм. Чего? Типа DOS в браузере, но только браузер в браузере?

Comment: знаю, звучит странно. Но да - браузер в браузере.

Comment: И что этот браузер должен делать?

Comment: открывать сайт, где юзер может переходить по линкам

Comment: И чем эта функциональность будет отличаться от просто браузера? Может вы хотите изобрести iframe?

Comment: я знаю, что такое фреймы и как можно получать контент страниц другими методами. Мне интересен теоретический вопрос - возможно ли создать полный эмулятор, например на базе хрома или мазилы, и выводить его на страницу. Есть селениум, фантом, но они не позволяют так сказать "транслировать" картинку. Мне это интересно и я хочу это попробовать реализовать для себя ради практики.

Comment: А рендерить картинку для устройства пользователя вы где будете, на сервере что ли и передавать уже в виде графики ?

Comment: это не совсем то. Рендерить картинку не сложно, отдавая полученный dom.  Я ищу немного другие методы - что то вроде стрима картинки браузера в клиент.

Comment: Так вот у меня и вопрос, вы собираетесь гонять dom или готовую картинку (например canvas) ?

Comment: хочу в клиент доставлять картинку без анализа и манипулирования dom

Comment: На сколько я знаю современные web-игры используют для отрисовки canvas. так что можно транслировать изображение в него и на клиенте простенький скрипт выкладывает полученные элементы на холст, ну и удаляет не нужные

Comment: О, а еще же вам в обратку надо будет гнать поток событий мыши, вам же каждое движение надо знать, например что бы элементы подсвечивать при наведении. Не вздумайте делать это на http ... WebSocket явно нужен

Comment: Написали бы сразу понятно. Вам нужно что-то типа RDP, но не на компьютер пользователя, а к браузеру, который обрабатывает данные на сервере, а клиенту отдаёт только готовую картинку. В принципе, через то же веб-сокет, да, можно провернуть такое